# Velocity time graph for object moving in a uniform magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, magnetic-fields, vectors

I'm trying to strengthen my solving of differential equations, so as an exercise, I tried coming up with a function of velocity vs time for a particle moving in a uniform magnetic field initially perpendicular to the field in the same plane.

For consistency purposes, let's say the positive ion is moving with a velocity into the desktop monitor and the magnetic field direction is towards the left of the monitor. 
I said that:

$$m * \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = q\vec{v} \times B$$

But then I realized that the force is directed towards the top of the monitor, so this differential equation will not actually represent the magnitude of velocity, as it will start to have another component directed upwards immediately after entering the field. I'm in Calc II so I only understand separation of variables. Is there a way to incorporate this in the differential equation using this method?

Comment: Do you understand differential equation in two variables $v_y(t), v_z(t)$? This is basically what you've got in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: The differential equation obtained from the eom is a coupled differential equation. You can solve this by rewriting $\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$ in the form $A\vec{v}$ where $A$ is some matrix. The eom then simplifies to $\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{v}}{\mathrm{d}t}=A\vec{v}$ which is a matrix differential equation.

Comment: Alternatively you can use complex numbers to solve this problem. From the equation of motion you obtain two equations for each component of $\vec{v}$. You can define a new variable $z=v_x+i v_y$ and use the two equations to obtain a new equation in the form $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t}=iaz$ where $a$ is some constant. This is a simple linear ode.